# Want to implement web sockets in Laravel

Tags: laravel, push-notification, redis, laravel-5.6

I want to implement web notifications in Laravel using web sockets. I have
tried pusher. It is very easy but it is a paid package. I have also tried redis and socket.io for which I have to install horizon. I am running Windows and I cannot install it on Windows according to what I have read about horizon.

So I am very confused about push notification. I am trying for at least one week but haven't found any solution yet. My front end is in angluar 5/android and backend is in Laravel 5.6.

Can you please suggest me any good ideas to implement push notification?

Comment: You can use node.js

Comment: can you give me any reference or tutorial for doing that

Comment: This is a very simple example of chat application to have an idea of node.js with socket.io https://socket.io/get-started/chat/. You can control whom you want to send the notification.

Comment: try this stuff: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORga8ZavCc8&list=PLwAKR305CRO9rlj-U9oOi4m2sQaWN6XA8

Comment: they are using pusher

Comment: check out onesignal.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have been use pusher,so I assume you know how to use event.

I recommend you laravel-echo-server.It's very easy to use,with a built-in api.

Here is a fresh example of a laravel-echo project from scratch.
After you set up the project.

you will need predis if you haven't install it yet

```
composer require predis/predis
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

1. run  `npm install -g laravel-echo-server`
2. run `laravel-echo-server init`
3. uncomment `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` in `config/app.php`
4. add `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2.1.1/dist/socket.io.js"></script>` in your app.blade.php
5. you need a socketio-client ,you can run `npm install --save laravel-echo` .In case you are not familiar with npm or vue, you can simply include this compiled file from my github project.[compiledjs](https://github.com/evolot/echoexample/blob/master/public/js/echocompiled.js)
6. add this to app.blade.php

   ```
   <script>
   window.Echo = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'socket.io',

   host: '{{url('/').':6001'}}',
   });
   Echo.private(`App.User.{{Auth::id()}}`) // private channel
   .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
       console.log(e)

   });


   </script>
   ```
7. finally run laravel-echo-server start and open you project ,you will see

   ```
   [20:53:21] - Lv5OKDAcuSLsK1nBAAAE authenticated for: private- 
      App.User.1
   [20:53:21] - Lv5OKDAcuSLsK1nBAAAE joined channel: private-App.User.1
   ```
8. you can listen any event you want or other notifications
9. here is my github project [echo-example](https://github.com/evolot/echoexample)

add a little code so that you can use postman send message to specfic user.You can see the message from chrome  console.You can get more details from github project screenshots

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d). It covers implementing websocket in laravel using redis driver, Laravel echo and socket.io client.

According to above article:

**“Why don’t you just use Pusher?”**

Here is the thing.

Laravel comes with Pusher enabled. Even though Pusher seems like a quick “Plug and play” solution (which it is), it comes with limitations. Check https://pusher.com/pricing

And most of the tutorials trick you with their title of implementing Websockets when in reality they just want to give you Pusher. (And my favorite part is when they say that you can easily switch to socket.io)

Comment: exactly, they are just using socket.io keywords to click bait people. Yet, the article is actually about pusher. i guess pusher.com invested on these websitessss to funnel people to use their service. a clear marketing strategy. that's why i made a huge deal of time learning socket.io and i am proud i made it work.

Answer (score 2):

As per [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting), I will recommend using Pusher. I have created a package for to user WebSockets in laravel.

https://www.techzonemind.com/scalable-websocket-server-laravel-applications/

It will use Redis for background queuing to optimize performance. I have used it in few solutions. I may not be usable in all use cases. But good to have a look.

[image]

PHP not build to execute concurrent tasks, if you have a choice, nodejs will be a better solution,

Comment: can i use your package with redis and socket.io?

Comment: it does not need socket.io, package include websocket server.

Comment: okk i will try with your package and get back to you really thank u @Jithin

Answer (score 1):

**THE BEST WAY TO INTEGRATE REALTIME IN LARAVEL IS NIETHER NODE NOR PUSHER**

You find Pusher Easier and you don't want to pay the price . Then without hesitation you should try [Laravel Websockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) . Its a very simple Pusher Replacement .

In Short You use the pusher client libs to access a pusher like server that is hosted in your php server . Since its open source its free .
Its better than using socket.io or redis because they require you to pay additional
server costs .
You can check their demo app [here](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets-demo)

**PS**

If you want more custom controls then you can use [ratchet](http://socketo.me/)