# How to add a dynamic results section to Laravel

Tags: laravel, nonblocking

I made a laravel app which uses an index method that delivers a collection of the client's available appointments (think hairdresser) to the page (as an api), which I then display using vue/vuetify.

The client is saying they would like the appointments on the page to be dynamic/live eg if someone books an appointment, then all other logged in users will see that appointment disappear from the list on their screen.

I have no idea how I would do this, although I have had one idea - I somehow incorporate node/non-blocking on the server, like a chat room, but only for this part of the app.

Or is there a way to do this with laravel/nginx?

Thanks in advance - I don't know what to search for!

Comment: you can use event broadcasting and have the client side listening on channels to get updates ... quick thought

Comment: You probably want to use web-sockets, this may help as starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576336/want-to-implement-web-sockets-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `Broadcasting` [(Documentation Link)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting). You would need to:

1. Configure your broadcasting driver (you could give `pusher` a try for quick setup and tinkering)
2. Configure your Laravel backend to dispatch a new event whenever a new appointment is made, (e.g. `event(new AppointmentCreated($appointment))` where `AppointmentCreated` implements the `ShouldBroadcast` interface. You can combine this with [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events)
3. Update your frontend to receive your broadcast (Check [Laravel Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo)). Once you receive a broadcast, update the UI to mark this appointment as unavailable i.e, make it disappear