# Best practice for websockets / MySQL realtime data

Tags: php, mysql, websocket

I have a chat room that allows all guests on the website to view all messages but only authenticated users can post.

Posting is done via ajax to an api built in PHP.

At the moment all data for the chatroom is handled via ajax (with timed requests for new data) and now I want to switch that up to websockets (also in PHP using Ratchet).

I intend to keep the current ajax method for posting, but want the secure websocket to hand the posted data down to the client, both guests and authenticated members alike.

I have the socket set up and working but I'm not entirely sure what the best practice is for querying the chat database (MySql) to get the latest messages.

Currently I use the following to query the db for the latest 40 messages which as I mentioned above is done by ajax requests every 15 seconds... This data is then fitered by javascript on the client side to only append messages that they haven't already seen...

```
public static function read()
{
  $db = static::getDB();
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM chatbox ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 40';
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  return $results;
}
```

... but I'm struggling to see how I can get this data via the websocket script without constantly querying the database with some kind of polling method which defeats the whole idea of using websockets to cut down on polling.

Basically I want all connected clients to wait for any messages and when they are posted this data is sent down to them.

Is there something I need to do with MySQL to notify a PHP script everytime a new message is posted or is this the totally wrong approach?

I've searched around a bit and I can't seem to find the answer, so any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is that mysql is not suitable for the message broker role. You need to find a different solution for that, such as redis.

Comment: So bascially run a separate redis db and populate it with the messages from the mysql db? Okay I can see how that would be easy to do but then I'm still left with the same question.. How to poll the redis db for new data?

Comment: I am aware that I could use PHP to essentially fire an onMessage() in the websocket script every time a new message is posted in the db, but that felt like a long winded way to handle it.

Comment: I suggest not redis, but a message queue like RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, etc.

Comment: No, redis (or any other message broker you decide to use) delivers the messages to all subscribed clients. Those messages that you want to persist for a longer time are then pushed from the message broker to mysql. If you search on the Internet, you can find tutorials for various message brokers. Here is one for redis + laravel from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576336/want-to-implement-web-sockets-in-laravel

Comment: `I intend to keep the current ajax method for posting, but want the secure websocket to hand the posted data down to the client`...on the contrary, you should send the message using the socket too... that would deliver the message into the socket server so you could then easily pass that message on to the other clients, instantly. Then the database would only be needed for keeping a history of messages, rather than trying to make it behave as a message broker which it's not suitable for. the socket server would effectively be the broker, which is probably ok for a simple chat app